# Need help linking oracle tables in MS Access

Tags: oracle, ms-access, odbc, ms-access-2010, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am having some issues connection to an oracle DB using MS Access.

If I use SQL Developer to connect to the Oracle DB I see pretty much every table and view in the DB however when I connect using MS Access I only get a selected few.

I tough it was because the user didn't have Select privileges on the tables I need so I requested the privilege and after a moth of waiting I finally got it but I still cant see the tables on the Access tool.

This is what I see on SQL Developer vs MS access. I need SFMFG.PWUI_CHAR_DEF_EXT to show on access table manager. Any help to solve this mystery is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Are you using an ODBC connection, or is there a different way you have this connection defined?  Hate to say it...this still seems permission oriented.  The ODBC connection can have a different user account than yours setup

Comment: Yes It seems to be "Microsoft ODBC for Oracle" driver and is a .dsn connection.

Comment: The Linked Table Manager only shows tables already linked. For adding additional tables, see Dan's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Access 2010, if I select External Data ==> ODBC Database ==> Link to the datasource by creating a linked table, I get a windows dialogue of all the available datasources.  When I log in to the one I want, I see the names of all the tables I am authorized to select from.

The Linked Table Manager only shows the tables for which there are existing links.