# how to combine two different database table with ADO?

Tags: excel, vba, ado, recordset

Is it possible to combine an Oracle table and Access table in one recordset with ADO?

I can do it with two Access table but not able to do with one Oracle and one Access.
any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**
Working code with two access

```
Sub twoDB()
Dim con As ADODB.Connection
Dim strDB1 As String
Dim strDB2 As String
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

Set con = New ADODB.Connection
strDB1 = ".......\daotest.accdb"
strDB2 = ".......\daotest2.accdb"

mysql = "select * from [" & strDB1 & "].şubeler inner join [" & strDB2 & "].şb on (şb.şb=şubeler.SubeKodu)"

With con
    .ConnectionString = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; data source=" & strDB2 'oledb, odbc için: con.ConnectionString = "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=" & strDB 'odbc
    .Mode = adModeWrite
    .Open
End With

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open mysql, con, adOpenDynamic, adLockReadOnly

ActiveCell.CopyFromRecordset rs

End Sub
```

Non-Working code with one access and one oracle

```
Sub twoDBOneOracleOneAccess()
Dim con As ADODB.Connection
Dim strDB2 As String
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

Set con = New ADODB.Connection

strDB2 = "....\daotest2.accdb"

mysql = "select MUSTERI_ID,MUSTERI_BAGLI_OLDUGU_SUBE_ID from OracleTable a inner join [" & strDB2 & "].şb on (şb.şb=a.MUSTERI_BAGLI_OLDUGU_SUBE_ID) where A.MESLEK_KODU=2041"

With con
    .ConnectionString = "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source........;"
    .Open
End With

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open mysql, con, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic

ActiveCell.CopyFromRecordset rs

End Sub
```

Comment: Does the Access database know about the Oracle table? A recordset is nothing but the result of a query, the link between Access and Oracle isn't in the recordset, it needs to be in the database you're querying. Also, what kind of recordset? I'm assuming you mean a forward-only, "query results" recordset, but ADO has much and more features. Your question is currently too vague to be answerable, and note that yes/no answers aren't happening on this site.

Comment: Hi Mat's, i actually meant "how to do it", not "if it was possible". so i think my quesiton is still legitimate. Access doesn't know about the Oracle table. this is the my question anyway. how i can i let access  know abotu oracle or the vice versa? i'm gonna put a sample code now above as an edit

Comment: "how to do it" means you're expecting someone to come here and write you a tutorial about "how to do it", which isn't how this site works, at all, so no, your question is not going to fly. Do your research/homework, *then* ask here when you hit a *specific* roadblock.

Comment: of course i'm not expecting someone to write code for me, i just need someone tell me the way, give me the hint. i can do the rest

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25249340/1188513

Comment: Thanks, but i need a solution with ADO, so both i can generalize this with other DB's in which importing/linking is not possible and i can do the other stuff with VBA. Sometimes i wiill need to connect DB2 and Oracle and SQL Server tables as well.